# ListPlot and ListLinePlot coloring bugs

Tags: graphics

I can't believe these bugs are still around.

```
ListPlot[Transpose@Table[{n, n + 2}, {n, 1, 10}], Joined -> True, Mesh -> Full]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose@Table[{n, n + 2}, {n, 1, 10}], Mesh -> Full]
```

[image]

These problems have been asked before, but they have never been tagged as bugs. We need to report these as bugs.

Comment: Okay, why don't you report them as bugs if you think they are ? Do we need a separate question just for that ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this post as off-topic because it is not a question.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your motivation was for posting this.  Are you looking for a workaround?  If so, please make that explicit.  In that case, also link to the previous questions about the same (are there answers with workarounds there)?  Or are you just trying to get the bug fixed?  In that case, you should contact Wolfram support. StackExchange sites are specifically for questions (which this post doesn't seem to be), not for bug reports. Mathematica.SE is not run by WRI, and they may never even notice your post. To ensure that WRI knows about the bug, you need to contact them instead.

Comment: It's important to understand that *posting bugs here won't get them fixed*.  People who use this site as users like you, not Wolfram employees who get to decide what gets fixed in the next release.  We all want the bugs to get fixed. The best way to do that is to writ to [Wolfram Support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/).  Posting here is not enough even if the post is made to be a proper question.  That's why whenever I see a question that turns out to be due to a bug, I always ask people *to report it to WRI support!*